# WM_TOUCH acts differetly in Windows-8.1

Tags: touch, windows-8.1, wm-touch

I have a Windows application using WM_TOUCH message to handle touch screen.

It works fine in Windows 7 and Windows 8.0.

In Win 8.1 the WM_TOUCH behaves differently:
Win7: WM_TOUCH with flag eTouchDown is continuously received when I touch the window
Win8.1: WM_TOUCH with flag eTouchDown is received only once

Win7: WM_TOUCH with flag eTouchUp is received when I lift my finger
Win8.1: WM_TOUCH with flag eTouchDown is NOT received when I lift my finger

Windows documentation does not indicate any change in WM_TOUCH behavior in Windows 8.1.

I would like to have the same application work on Win7, Win8 & Win8.1, so using the newer API with WM_POINTER is not feasible.

I will be happy to know if this is a known issue and if there is a way to get WM_TOUCH working properly in Windows 8.1.

Thanks a lot,
Rotem

Answer (score 0):

Did you RegisterTouchWindow() in your application?